# CSS float property creates phantom margin

Tags: html, css

[you can view the problem here](http://arthouse.comlu.com)

so i lovingly build my humble little site, I have a div with content, nested snugly within my content div are two paragraphs and a header. I decide to float an image to the right within my content div expecting the paragraph to wrap around it, it happens as expected BUT it creates a phantom margin between my header banner and my content div, i search and search and search and search for the offending code until i can stand it no more! and decide to put my SOS in a bottle and launch it towards stackoverflow, please help me or I may end up on suicide watch within 24-48hrs.

here is the html and code, please dont laugh i am a noob and have only been learning css and html for about three weeks:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 769px)"/>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px)"/>
<link href="media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 479px)"/>
<title>MSK Chess</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <h1>MSK Chess</h1>
    </div>
<div id="container">
<div id="container2">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nav item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="more"> <!--right column-->
        <h3>Chess goodies</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet. </p>
        <a href="#"><img src="chessjam.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="content"><!--left column-->
        <div class="right"><img src="image.gif" alt="" width="100" height="100"><br>Chess blah</div><p> 
        <h2>Chess is Awesome</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>

    </div>
    <div id="cleardiv"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Footer item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Footer item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Footer item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Copyright &copy; mirsultankhan.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="vcss.gif"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

```
body
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 95%;
font-family: georgia, times, "times new roman", serif;
color: #000;
background-color: #fff;
}

div#banner
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

div.right{
float:right;
margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
border: 1px solid #666;
padding: 10px;
width:102px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-top: 1px solid #999;
border-right: 2px solid #555;
border-bottom: 2px solid #555;
border-left: 1px solid #999;
 }

 div.right img{
border-top: 2px solid #555;
border-right: 1px solid #999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
border-left: 2px solid #555;
  }



 div#banner h1
 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: .3em 0 .3em .5em;
 font-size: 2.2em;
 font-weight: normal;
  }



div#container
{margin:0;
background-image: url(nav_col_base.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

div#container2
{margin:0;
background-image: url(more_col_base.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: right;
}

div#navigation
{
float: left;
width: 150px;
padding-top: 2em;
}

div#navigation ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

div#navigation ul li { margin-top: 4px; }

#navigation ul li a
{
display: block;
width: 135px;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
background-image: url(nav_base.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #ccc;
background-image: url(nav_base2.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

div#more
{
float: right;
width: 160px;
margin: 0;
padding: 2em 10px 0 0;
color: #fff;
}

div#more h3
{
margin-top: 0;
color: #fff;
padding: .2em;
background-image: url(more_base.jpg);
background-position: right;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

div#content
{
margin-left: 190px;
margin-right: 200px;
}

div#content h2
{
font-size: 2em;
color: #036;
margin: 0;
font-weight: normal;
}

div#content { line-height: 150%; }

#cleardiv
{
clear: both;
height: 1em;
}

div#footer
{
clear: both;
padding: .5em 1em;
border-top: 1px solid #999;
text-align: center;
background-color:#E0E0E0;
height: 80px;
}

div#footer ul
{
padding: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
}

div#footer li
{
display: inline;
margin-right: 1em;
background-size: cover;
padding:3px 5px 3px 5px;
} 

div#footer a{
padding: 3px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #036;
} 

div#footer ul li a:hover
{
color: #000;
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Many thanks for taking the time - kind regards Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unnecessary <p> tag at the end of the following line (line # 31) in your html:

```
<div class="right"><img src="image.gif" alt="" width="100" height="100"><br>Chess blah</div><p>
```

Remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you kindly dear sir, thank you kindly indeed! it removes it and everything is fine fine fine!  many thanks for taking the time - kind regards robbie :D

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty `<p>` tag before your `<h2>Chess is Awesome</h2>` tag. That paragraph has a default top margin, which collapses into the zero margin of its parent, the `<div id="content">` element, effectively applying that margin to the `<div id="content">` itself, moving it away from the banner.

I assume that empty paragraph is there in order to offset the `<h2>` from the top of the `<div id="content">`. You can replace the empty paragraph with a `<br>` tag for the same purpose, or you can give the `<div id="content">` a `padding: 1px` style in order to separate its margin from the `<p>` margin, avoiding their collapse.

Comment: great one! thankyou for your help - an empty paragraph tag, ouch! the shame of it! after i searched and searched every margin on the page last night for hours, you are awesome - many thanks - regards robbie